# Can we have Abstraction without Encapsulation or vice versa?

Tags: oop, encapsulation, abstraction

I faced this question in an interview. I came back and read up about it here on SO and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960918/how-encapsulation-is-different-from-abstraction-as-a-object-oriented-concept-in), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742341/difference-between-abstraction-and-encapsulation) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10622628/encapsulation-abstraction), and many other duplicates saying almost the same thing.

I understand that the general definitions predate their implementations in programming languages. I also know that programming languages (I speak for Java) try to separate the two definitions as much as possible. For ex: Java considers `class` as encapsulation, as provides a wrapper to hold all your similar data; and `interface` is a kind of abstraction.

But what I really want to know is how do the two definitions overlap? `Are the two subsets, overlapping, or completely disjoint sets.` I understand that the definitions change wrt to generic definitions and language specific definitions, so answer both if you can, or atleast mention the one you're talking about.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22191855/126014

Comment: That's a brilliant way to explain abstraction I must say, but the answer doesn't mention anything about encapsulation.

Comment: I prefer Bertrand Meyer's definition of encapsulation, which I briefly describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31133372/126014 You can also learn more about it in [my Pluralsight course on encapsulation (and SOLID)](http://bit.ly/encapsulationsolid).